# r.walk issues in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, cost-path, pixel, cell-size

I have been doing the r.walk analysis but fail to generate the result. The movement direction map and walking cost map from stop points is extremely small, limited to a 3x3 or 5x5 square. Does anyone know about this issue?

The DEM is a 90m SRTM DEM.
[image]

Comment: Can you post the outputs from `g.region -p` and `r.info <your_DEM>` ??

Comment: You may also consider to use the new NASADEM ~30m. There is a convenient addon for the import: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.in.nasadem.html

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I forget to project my map first...thats why... lmao @Micha